# BSD for the NXT

Tags: operating-system, bsd, firmware, lego-mindstorms, nxt

Is it possible for me to "port" the BSD operating system over to the Lego Mindstorms NXT? If yes, has any body done it yet? Are there any examples?

Answer (score 3):

Forget it. The main µC has just 256kB Flash and 64kB RAM (says [LEGO](http://cache.lego.com/downloads/education/9797_LME_UserGuide_US_low.pdf)). This is several orders of magnitude too small for any Unix-like Operating System.

Comment: That is, modern UNIX variants. Dig for pre-1985 UNIX variants if you need to port it.